# Insert Image into Word by using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

Given is the path of a picture. How can I add the picture to a word document by using VBA code?

Comment: Show us the relevant code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **concept** of adding image to word document.

Create a template document ,let say in c:\path\file.docx

add an image where ever you like (this will be the frame to hold the new image )

select the image and insert a bookmark and name it something like "someBookmarkName".

And now from access use this code

```
Sub insertImageToWord()
Dim Word As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim filePath As String: filePath = "c:\path\file.docx"
Dim SHP As Object
Dim strTmp As String: strTmp = "someBookmarkName"
Dim strPath As String: strPath = "c:\path\image_file.png"

Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set doc = Word.Documents.Open(filePath)
Set SHP = doc.Bookmarks(strTmp).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Filename:=strPath, _
    LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=True)
With SHP
    'this will keep ratio
    '   .WrapFormat.type = 1  'wdWrapTight
    '   .WrapFormat.type = 7  'wdWrapInline
    .LockAspectRatio = -1    ' msoTrue
    'this will adjust width to 0.5 inch
    '.Width = wd.InchesToPoints(2.5)
    ' .Width = wd.CentimetersToPoints(2.66) * 2.5
    ' .Height = wd.CentimetersToPoints(3.27) * 2.5
    '   .ScaleHeight = 150
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Hello xShen. Basically your code is working. There are an issue, the bookmarked picture is still in the new document. I will try to enhance the solution, that the Proportion of the bookmarked picture will be used.

Comment: Hi dev. I looked in old word document that use this technique , and over there the holding frame is a Text Box. so try to switch from picture to Text box.

Comment: @xShen I realize this is a bit of necroposting, but your solution is the exact solution I am looking for. My use case is signing documents using Access (long story). However, I am running into the "Object Required" error, and I am thinking it most likely a missing Reference... what references are required for this?

Comment: Hi there , this is late binding so no Reference needed. try to google for GetObject( ,"Word.Application", )   instead of CreateObject("Word.Application").